# Bypassing update blocker in non-route component with React Router and React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-hooks

I'm using React Router with a generic Page component that grabs the content from the WP Rest API based on the slug. I can visit the pages directly via url and routing works.

I have a small menu in my Footer component that use the React Router `<Link>` component linking to the various pages using the Page component.

When I click these links, the url is updating but the Page component is not re-rendering with the updated slug and thus not grabbing the correct page content.

This is definitely update blocking as described in the React Router docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking

That covers most of the solutions however in my case the Footer component is not a Route and is a child of the Layout component which is also route-less and wraps all other components.

To fix, the docs suggest that I would need to send the React Router `location` prop down the component tree.

I've tried exporting all of the components using `withRouter` down the component tree which should pass this prop down but it isn't working.

How can I get the `<Page>` component to update when I click on a `<Link>` in the `<Footer>` component?

Routes in App.js:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout
        addToCart={addToCart}
        removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
        clearCart={clearCart}
        cart={cart}
        catalog={catalog}
    >
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home catalog={catalog} />} />
            <Route
                exact
                path="/catalog"
                render={() => (
                    <Catalog addToCart={addToCart} catalog={catalog} />
                )}
            />
            <Route path="/:slug" render={props => <Page {...props} />} />
            <Route
                path="/catalog/:category/:slug"
                render={() => (
                    <SingleProduct addToCart={addToCart} catalog={catalog} />
                )}
            />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Layout.js (simplified):

```js
<Layout>
    <Header />
    {children}
    <Footer />
<Layout
```

Links in `<Footer />`:

```js
<ul className="nostyle footer-links">
    <li>
        <Link to="/faq">FAQ</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to="/contact">Contact Us</Link>
    </li>
</ul>
//...
export default withRouter(Footer)
```

Page.js:

```js
const Page = props => {
    const slug = props.match.params.slug
    const [page, setPage] = useState()

    const fetchPage = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
            `${params.liveUrl}${params.pages}?slug=${slug}`
        )
        setPage(result.data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPage()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="page" key={page[0].slug}>
                {page[0].content}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Page)
```

So if I visit `/faq` or `/about` directly, it loads the `<Page />` component as directed in the Route, passing in the slug and everything displays properly.

But, if I click one of the links in `<Footer />`, the url changes but the `<Page />` component is not refreshed with the new slug and thus the correct page data. If I reload the page, the correct data is loaded.

How can I force the `<Page>` component to update when the Route is changed?

Note that I am using React hooks and not using Redux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the unique key for your Page component, so a new instance of this component would render every time a key changes.

Assuming your slug is unique, you can do the following:

```
<Page key={props.match.params.slug} {...props} />
```

Alternatively, you can also do it like this:

```
<Page key={window.location.pathname} {...props} />
```

Comment: Thanks - that was it! Makes perfect sense.